# Setting object 'equal' to a Window class

Tags: c#, wpf, user-interface, object

I know this might be one of the dumbest questions ever, but...

I'm trying to set one of my windows equal to an object, like this:

```
object extrasWindow = IsWindowOpen<pgAddQouteExtras>();
```

Then I have a method called `ExportDatagrid()`

```
public void ExportDatagrid(object sender)
{
    if (extrasWindow != null)
    {

    }
}
```

In this method I would like to set my `extrasWindow` 'equal' to the `object sender` to access the UI elements of the window `pgAddQouteExtras`. Something like this:

```
public void ExportDatagrid(object sender)
{
    if (extrasWindow != null)
    {
        sender = extrasWindow.dgViewProjects; 
    }
}
```

The only problem I have is that I can't access the UI element of the other window because I can't reach the datagrid like `extrasWindow.dgViewProjects`. I can only get:

`extrasWindow.Equals`
`extrasWindow.GetHashCode`
`extrasWindow.GetType`
`extrasWindow.ToString`

Is there some type that I have to set my Window to that would allow me access to the page's UI elements?

Answer (score 0):

It's unclear exactly what your method `IsWindowOpen<pgAddQuoteExtras>` returns. Usually a method prefixed with `Is` returns a `boolean`. Assuming your method returns a `pgAddQuoteExtras` which has a `dgViewProjects` member then `sender` can be cast using the [as](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cscsdfbt.aspx) casting operator like this:

```
public void ExportDatagrid(object sender)
{
    var extrasWindow = sender as pgAddQuoteExtras;
    if (extrasWindow != null)
    {
        var projects = extrasWindow.dgViewProjects; 
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you try to compile this?

Comment: Sorry, I did not and I forgot the actual assignment. Edit has been made.